# Android Camera2, take picture continuously

Tags: android, freeze, preview, camera2

I need to take pictures continuously with Camera2 API. It works fine on high end devices (for instance a Nexus 5X), but on slower ones (for instance a Samsung Galaxy A3), the preview freezes.

The code is a bit long, so I post only the most relevant parts:

Method called to start my preview:

```
private void startPreview() {

    SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();

    if(texture != null) {

        try {

            // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());

            // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

            // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
            mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

            // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

                        // If the camera is already closed, return:
                        if (mCameraDevice == null) { return; }

                        // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                        mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;

                        // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                        mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();

                        // Start the preview
                        try { mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest, null, mPreviewBackgroundHandler); }
                        catch (CameraAccessException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Configure failed");
                    }
                }, null
            );
        }
        catch (CameraAccessException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Method called to take a picture:

```
private void takePicture() {

    try {

        CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        captureBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
        mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), null, mCaptureBackgroundHandler);
    }
    catch (CameraAccessException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

And here is my ImageReader:

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(final ImageReader reader) {

        mSaveBackgroundHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Set the destination file:
                File destination = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "image_" + mNumberOfImages + ".jpg");
                mNumberOfImages++;

                // Acquire the latest image:
                Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();

                // Save the image:
                ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                buffer.get(bytes);

                FileOutputStream output = null;
                try {
                    output = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                    output.write(bytes);
                }
                catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                finally {

                    image.close();

                    if (null != output) {

                        try { output.close(); }
                        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                    }
                }

                // Take a new picture if needed:
                if(mIsTakingPictures) {
                    takePicture();
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

I have a button that toggle the mIsTakingPictures boolean, and makes the first takePicture call.

To recap, I'm using 3 threads:

- one for the preview
- one for the capture
- one for the image saving

What can be the cause of this freeze?

Comment: Hi, I know that this is a bit old topic but can you please share the implementation of the mPreviewBackgroundHandler, mCaptureBackgroundHandler and I assume mImageSavingBackgroundHandler?

Comment: Also, I can see that you call the takePicture method for repeating the capture but where do you call the takePicture for the first time?

Comment: Hi, sorry but I'm no longer working for the same company, and I no longer have access to this code.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to avoid framing lost in your preview when you are taking images all time on weak devices. The only way to avoid this is on devices which support `TEMPLATE_ZERO_SHUTTER_LAG` and using a `reprocessableCaptureSession`. The documentation about this is pretty horrible and find a way to implement it can be a odyssey. I have this problem a few months ago and finally I found the way to implement it:

[How to use a reprocessCaptureRequest with camera2 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163704/how-to-use-a-reprocesscapturerequest-with-camera2-api/41343005#41343005)

In that answer you can also find some Google CTS test's which also implements ReprocessableCaptureSession and shoot some burst captures with ZSL template.

Finally, you can also use a `CaptureBuilder` with your preview surface and the image reader surface attached, in that case your preview will continue working all time and also you will save each frame as a new picture. But you will still having the freeze problem.

I also tried implement a burst capture using a handler which dispatch a new `capture` call each 100 milliseconds, this second option was pretty good in performance and avoiding frame rate lost, but you will not get as many captures per second like the two `ImageReader` option.

Hope that my answer will help you a bit, API 2 still being a bit complex and there's not so many examples or information about it.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I noticed on low end devices: the preview stops after a capture, even when using camera 1 api, so it has to be restarted manually, thus producing a small preview freeze when capturing a high resolution picture.

But the camera 2 api provides the possibility to get raw image when taking a still capture (that wasn't possible on the devices I have when using camera 1 (Huawei P7, Sony Xperia E5, wiko UFeel)). Using this feature is much faster than capturing a JPEG (maybe due to JPEG compression), so the preview can be restarted earlier, and the preview freeze is shorter. Of course using this solution you'll have to convert the picture from YUV to JPEG in a background task..